Is the wand gripping style up to preference, or does the method of holding the wand serve a specific purpose?
I have recently become interested in the correct way to hold a wizarding wand from Harry Potter.
Firstly, is the handiness left or right depending task, and if so, can one be ambidextrous? After watching the movies, most characters seem to hold their wands with their left hand, except for Voldemort, who changes the hands in which he holds his wand. I know the movies may differ from the books, as the actors most likely held their wand in whatever way seemed comfortable for them. 
When doing this research, I came across someone with a similar problem where they had a wand that was meant to be Hermione's wand and found it uncomfortable to hold in the left hand. I found this to be true, as I have the same wand.
Most characters, including Harry and Hermione, hold their wands by placing them in the middle of their palms and wrapping their fingers and thumbs around them. I looked back at the left-handed pictures of Voldemort and found he held his wand differently: he lets the bottom of his wand sit on the tip of his pinky, middle, and ring fingers equally spread apart, then his index finger is pointed outward toward the edge of the wand with his thumb on top.
I found Bellatrix does similar, but her fingers are on top and her thumb on bottom. I find that this position that feels best for me is a variation of Voldemort's, where it’s the same except that my middle and pointer finger rest on the second buckle instead.
So is the wand gripping style up to preference, or does the method of holding the wand serve a specific purpose?

I have nothing to offer on wand techniques, but this question is very hard to read. Most of it is one very long sentence. You may have a better chance of getting good answers if you can improve the readability by breaking it up into shorter sentences and paragraphs, and looking at the spelling and punctuation. Also, this doesn't seem to be a "character-identification" question - that tag is for asking questions like "who is the character who turns Harry into a newt in Book 5?"

I've done what I can to help with editing this question - I hope that it's what the OP was meaning to ask.

It might help if you could clarify the scope -- are you talking movies?  Books?  Both?  And are you talking pragmatically?  Or if there is a canon answer? (I.e., Some spells require a firm grip as there is feedback to the wand.  Some must be cast left handed ('sinister') inherently, etc., as stated by the author and/or derived works?) The feel I got from the questions was closer to as a Cosplay background question, and if that's not what you are going for, clarity would help.

Often, the way to hold something is also the most efficient way not to drop it. In other cases, such as a bow and arrow, it's the way to aim it. I don't think there is a way to correctly hold a wand though. It's up to individual preference.

I believe that wand gripping is left to preference.  As stated, wands are simply a tool to refine the power inside of the people, not the source of the power.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It would help if you could supply some sources for this.  You say "as stated," but where is that stated?
